# Outline effect using flipped normals while keeping object underneath still lit normally?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, npr

I am trying to use the toon shader as my base shader and the solidify modifier to create the outline effect but the shading of the object within the outline mesh is being shaded darker is there a way to have this part of the mesh react normally to the scene lights. The material being used for the outline effect doesn't cast shadows but it still seems to be effecting the interior mesh. Anyway to keep the toon shader looking like the sphere in the middle but with the outline?

[image]